# How to run a Powershell Script in a Azure Virtual Machine using Azure Functions or Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to start an Powershell Script on a Windows Virtual Machine on Azure using Azure Functions or Azure Logic App. So, I would like to know if this is possible und How can i do that

Comment: welcome to SO.  To get better responses to questions please check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Function app in powershell, e.g. using VS Code or Azure Portal.
Please follow the MS guide that describes how to create your first Function App using VS code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal

In the ps code of the function app you need use the `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` cmdlet to run a PowerShell script on an Azure VM. The cmdlet expects the script referenced in the -ScriptPath parameter to be local to where the cmdlet is being run.

Here is the the sample usage format:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

*Note:*
Listing the run commands or showing the details of a command requires the Microsoft.Compute/locations/runCommands/read permission on Subscription Level. The built-in **Reader role** and higher levels have this permission.

*Running* a command requires the Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/action permission. The **Virtual Machine Contributor** role and higher levels have this permission.

You can use one of the built-in roles or create a custom role to use Run Command.